# C++ Dereferencing Null ptr error?

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference, null-pointer

I looked before posting, but pardon me if my answer is elsewhere. As part of my homework, I need to create an array of pointers to objects (of different types, but they share a base class). Once the pointers are in the array I need to be able to call member functions on the objects to which they point. I'm able to do this for the first object, but after my program goes through the loop once, I get the following exception:  "0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000"

Below is my code. Thanks

```
int main()
{
    Sales * publications[5]; //declare an array of pointers
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i < 3)
            publications[i] = new Book();
        else
            publications[i] = new Tape();
        std::cout << std::endl << publications[i] << std::endl;
        (*publications)[i].readData();
        (*publications)[i].displayData();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //delete the array to avoid memory leak
        delete publications[i];
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I have already tested the readData and displayData functions and they work just fine.

Comment: If you review the lines in your `main()` which access `publications`, something should not make sense to you. If you ponder, for a moment, why you access `publications` in two different ways, as `publications[i]` and `(*publications)[i]`, for no apparent reason, whatsoever, you should be able to figure out the answer yourself.

Comment: `(*publications)[i]` is equivalent to `publications[0][i]`.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
(*publications)[i].readData();
```

Should be:

```
publications[i]->readData();
```

Comment: Well now my code works but I'm afraid I don't understand why it works.

Comment: `publications` is an array of pointers to `Sales` objects. `(*publications)` is the same as `publications[0]` - they are retrieving the first pointer in the array. When you apply `->` to a pointer retrieved from `publications`, you are accessing the members of that particular `Sales` object. But if you apply `[i]` to that `Sales*` pointer, you are treating it as if it a pointer to another array, which it is not.  So `(*publications)[i].readData()` (same as `publications[0][i].readData()`) is calling `readData` on a very different memory address than `publications[i]->readData()` is called on.

Answer (score 2):

`publications` is an array of pointers.

```
(*publications)[i].readData();
```

In this code snippet, the order of operations is out of order. The `*` dereference operator is going to take precedence over the `[]` array syntax operator due to the parenthesis.

The first thing that is going to happen is `publications` (the array) is going to be dereferenced - not the element located at index `i`. This will always give you the first element in the array, as an array variable is just the address of the first element.

The second operation that takes place is that a byte offset (`sizeof(Sales) * i)`) is added to the memory address returned by the dereference.  When the index `i` is 0, this is not a problem since there is no offset to add and an object exists at the calculated memory location. However, once you have an index not equal to 0, the calculated memory address does not point at a valid `Sales` object, so you may or may not crash, depending on what actually lies at the memory location.

The correct order of operations using the given operators is this:

```
(*(publications[i])).readData();
```

Using the `->` operator is preferred instead:

```
publications[i]->readData();
```

Now, the `[]` array-syntax operator takes precedence, offsetting the address of the array to an element within the array, and then either `*.` or `->` is used to dereference that element's pointer to reach the object, as expected.